# Nginx: conditional "expires" directive

Tags: nginx

I wanted to create `if` block for `expires` directive, but it's not allowed in `if` context.

Like that:

```
if($args ~ "no_caching=1") {
  expires      epoch;
}
```

Is it somehow possible to create this in any other way?

I need nginx to change `expire header` to `epoch` when simple `$_GET` param `no_cache=1` is in present.

For visual checking purposes.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($arg_no_caching = 1) {
    expires max;
}
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24arg_PARAMETER